# Why doesn't Lagrange Interpolation work well in this case?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, interpolation-theory

So I was asked to use Lagrange interpolation to find the an approximation for the population at a given year.

```
def InterpolateLagrange(x, y, xval):

   #usage: InterpolateLagrange(x, y)
       #x: array of x-values
       #y: array of y-values
       #xval: x-value, for which the y-value should be obtained
     
   #output: 
       #yval: y-value

   #establish the inital y-value (yval)
   yval = 0.0
   
   #assign the length of x as n
   n= len(x)
   
   #for loop which will go through each integer of n
   for i in range(n):
       #Establish the initial term value 
       term = y[i]
       for j in range(n):
           if j != i:
               #Implement the Lagrange method any time  i does not equal j
               term = term * (xval - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j])
       
       #The the be the collectve sum of all the term values
       yval += term
   
   #Returns the yval which correlates to xval
   return yval
```

I used the method above for my data, however the yval value I received was incorrect.

```
year = np.array([1841., 1851., 1861., 1871., 1881., 1891., 1901., 1911., 1926.,
      1936., 1946., 1951., 1956., 1961., 1966., 1971., 1979., 1981.,
      1986., 1991., 1996., 2002., 2006., 2011.])
pop = np.array([6528799., 5111557., 4402111., 4053187., 3870020., 3468694.,
      3221823., 3139688., 2971992., 2968420., 2955107., 2960593.,
      2898264., 2818341., 2884002., 2978248., 3368217., 3443405.,
      3540643., 3525719., 3626087., 3917203., 4239848., 4588252.])

x = year
y = pop
xval = 1868

InterpolateLagrange(x, y, xval)


#Output -5805741994.539
```

But that's okay, this was expected and I found a better approximation using cubic spline interpolation.

But my question is **why** didn't Lagrange interpolation work with the given data?

Is it because the interpolation of the points (in this case) are growing too quickly  with n?
Any information on the topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE! Are you sure this is a mathematical problem? Have you ruled out that this code could produce erroneous results simply because of numerical overflows?

Comment: [Overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)

Comment: @user3733558 OP was sent from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66905270/why-doesnt-lagrange-interpolation-work-well-in-this-case). I think it's about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon or something like that, so that high-degree polynomial interpolation just goes crazy in layman's terms. There is no actual sample point at x=1868

Comment: @tevemadar thanks for the info, it clarifies things quite a bit. Nevertheless, the OP should have mentioned something along those lines, and I therefore felt I had to ask.

Comment: Check your implementation. You probably want to initialize with `term = 1`, then tack on the `y[i]` after the inner loop. At the moment term involves high powers of `y[i]`, when it ought to appear linearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the data points $(x_0,y_0),...,(x_n,y_n)$, where $x_0<...<x_n$.

These data points are samples (without error) of a function $f$.

We'll call $P\left(f\middle| x_0,\ldots,x_k\right)\left(x\right)$ the interpolation polynomial we get when interpolating through the points $(x_0,y_0),...,(x_k,y_k)$.

Given that $f$ is at least $n+1$ times continuously differentiable, the following estimation holds:

$$|f\left(x\right)-P\left(f\middle| x_0,\ldots,x_n\right)\left(x\right)
|\le \left|\max_{\xi\in [l,r]}
\frac{f^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(\xi\right)}{\left(n+1\right)!}\prod_{i=0}^{n}{x-x_i}\right|$$

Here, the LHS is your estimation error.

Let's make the additional assumption that all derivatives of $f$ are bounded by a constant $\pm c$ .
Then, adding a new point to the polynomial $P(f|x_0,...,x_k)(x)$ adds a factor
$$\ge \left| \frac{x-x_i}{n+1}\right|$$

You have $n=24$, and the data points are at least $5$ years apart each.
So, given our assumptions so far, every data point more than $24$ years away from the point you want to estimate will at most worsen the result.

Answer (score 1):

Your program using Lagrange interpolation is correct, but the
result of this interpolation has problems. I ran the equivalent
program with Mathematica using rational arithmetic but using
only some of the data points. That is, using only $15$ to
$21$ of the data points, the results for year $1868$ are
$$ 4130172, 4214080, 4342304, 4007068, -164106, -23688203, -126349191. $$
By $n=19$ the result is negative and gets worse from then on.
If you look at the trend, the results look reasonable up to
$n=13$. Probably the best you can hope for is with $n=5$ with
result $4134547$. In this case, as in others, adding more data
points away from the target year $1868$ does not give better results.

Using other interpolation methods can give much better results.
For example, Mathematica, using only the first $5$ data points
returns the result $4131597$ and adding more data points does
not change the result because it is effectively ignoring the
extra data points.